# When is Fixed Interest Allowed?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis, organizations

It says in an [article at VBM Torah](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak65/14halak.htm):

> It should be remembered that Halakha makes explicit mention of particular bodies to whom it is permissible to lend at interest (e.g., the community)

So what Jewish institutions / bodies are we allowed to lend to at fixed interest and under what circumstances?

What are the sources for this allowance?

Answer (score 1):

אבק רבית (rabbinically-forbidden ribis) is allowed in certain cases, such as to benefit the estate of orphans (Rambam Hilchos Malveh 4:14):

> נכסי יתומים מותר ליתן אותם לאדם נאמן שיש לו נכסים טובים קרוב לשכר
>   ורחוק להפסד. כיצד אומר לו תהיה נושא ונותן בהן אם יש שם ריוח תן להם
>   חלקן מן הריוח ואם יש שם הפסד תפסיד אתה לבדך שזה אבק רבית הוא וכל אבק
>   רבית אינה אסורה אלא מדבריהם ובנכסי יתומים לא גזרו:

See also: http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/ribis1.html

> the Maharam Schick and Rav Shlomo Greenfeld considered a bank's unique
>   status as a corporation; its owners are not personally liable for any
>   debts incurred on their part. Thus any Ribis would not pass from
>   creditor to debtor, but rather from a lifeless entity to real people.
>   This unique state they perceived as a mitigating, but not totally
>   exonerating, factor They allow a corporation to collect (Ribis that is
>   of rabbinic origin) or permits Ribis if the organization is also a
>   charity or acting on behalf of an estate.

...

> In the interests of benefiting philanthrophic institutions and of
>   protecting the rights of heirs not legally competent (generally
>   children), our Rabbis permitted estates and Zedaka organizations to
>   lend money and charge interest if the infraction is mid'rabbanan (of
>   rabbinic origin). Under no circumstances may these institutions engage
>   in deals involving Ribis d'oraitha (prohibited by the Torah) even if
>   the deal is arranged with a broker's assistance.

Comment: If by fixed interest you mean ribis ketzutza (i.e. ribis d'oraissa) I don't believe there is ever sucha heter.

Comment: Part of this answer is about which *lenders* can lend with interest, which doesn't address the question, which was about *borrowers*.

Comment: In which case the answer should be: none (unless the lender is a tzedaka organization and it is only a case of avak ribis). The issur ribis is on both sides; so too the heter.